# Deploying django application in production?

Tags: python, django, git

I have installed [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/install/#installing-an-official-release-with-pip) and [mod_wsgi-express](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) (the *new* way) on an ubuntu 15.10 server using:

```
pip install Django
pip install mod_wsgi
```

Currently I am starting/deploying my django application using a script that:

```
cd ~/.local/bin
./mod_wsgi-express start-server ~/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

where my application is located in (as a git repository):

```
~/mysite/
```

Since `~/mysite/` is not on the **PYTHONPATH** I have modified the **wsgi.py** file to:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
# Hardcode the path to the application/add it to the PYTHONPATH
import sys
path = '/home/user/mysite'
if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This works fine for now. But if I want to use this in production I see some problems:

1. **wsgi.py** contains hard coded path to the django web application to make sure its in the PYTHONPATH. Further its not guaranteed to be in the same path on the local developer machine. At least an improvement could be to use relative paths.
2. The web application is distributed as a git repository. E.g. in java you would package it into a war or an ear file.
3. Both **django** and **mod_wsgi-express** are located in the ~/.local folder for a specific local user.

Are there any obvious changes I should start looking into to eliminate bullet 1-3 above or is the above approach more or less how django deployment works?

Comment: I'm not sure in what way points 2 and 3 are "problems".

Comment: I think 2-3 are fine for now.  It was more if there were some recommended practices for doing this.  E.g. in Java you typically package the web application into a war or ear file that then gets extracted inside the container.

Comment: Would `path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start out by saying that I'm assuming you're using the set up you describe for specific reasons and I won't try to steer you towards anything that might be more admin-friendly. If you're not and could use a friendly nudge, you can try Googling around for different people's pros/cons and examples or I would put in a good word for Gunicorn and an LTS version of Ubuntu.

Anyway.

When I was reading your question the first thing that popped into my head was that you could use something like Fabric or even just a deployment script that could do a string substitution in your `wsgi.py` file, putting in the correct path for you along with handling everything else in your deployment. I would say automated deployments are something of a standard and you might like the freedom of being able to throw out a server and spin up a new one in 5 minutes, but they can be a lot to learn if you're doing other things at the time.

Figuring that you probably didn't want to mess with all the automation rigmarole, I then popped over to [Django's mod_wsgi deployment documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/) (which is pretty good) because messing around with the Python path seemed weird and like something you shouldn't have to do. Sure enough, [they recommend running mod_wsgi in daemon mode](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/#using-mod-wsgi-daemon-mode), which gives you an opportunity to set the Python path in the Apache config and keep it separate from the code you distribute. Then you can just have different boxes use different config files based on their needs.

That same documentation has notes on using a virtual environment (virtualenv) which you also want to probably do -- that virtualenv would then be portable and would handle your concerns with point 3.

With point 2 you should probably just think of the git distribution as a feature -- no need to run a build process and upload WAR files and all the etceteras. Java people only put up with that because they theoretically get something from having their code compiled into bytecode; Python, for better or for worse, doesn't do any compilation so you can deploy your code transparently and use git to handle your files at all points in the application's life without worrying about keeping the artifact versions straight and all that.

EDIT:

You could also probably avoid any issues with PYTHONPATH by adding your ~/.local/bin folder to your path (`export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH` from command line) and then `cd`ing into your site's directory and just running `mod_wsgi-express start-server mysite/wsgi.py`. By adding the local bin folder to your PATH you gain the ability to reference any applications in it implicitly from any directory while still having everything rooted in the directory you `cd` into, which should keep Python from getting confused.

I would still prefer to link mod_wsgi into your main Apache installation and run it in daemon mode so that you can control bringing it up/down from systemd/systemctl instead of forking processes from your terminal and having to look up the process ID in `ps` to kill it.

Comment: Configuring mod_wsgi in daemon mode would require first installing the mod_wsgi modules into apache right? E.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/25374/how-do-you-install-mod-wsgi . I have read about Gunicorn which I might try a at later time. For now I would like to test/understand the apache approach. I installed mod_wsgi using the "new" way from: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi

Comment: I think it would, yes. Personally I'd prefer to do it that way anyway so that there's an OS daemon running your server that you can control with systemctl or systemd instead of forking off a process from your terminal and having to look up the ID in ps to kill it. Installing from within Python would be nice for a development box but for your actual production server I think it makes sense to tie it in directly to your Apache installation.

Answer (score 0):

Better something like this:
    import os
    import sys
    sys.path.append("add/Your/Path")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","mysite.settings")
    import django
    django.setup
    import django.core.handlers.wsgi
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

check that You project is named a mysite, If You project have other name change mysite on name of You django-project. You will use to production apache?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os 
import sys 
sys.path.append("add/Your/Path")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE","mysite.settings") 
import django 
django.setup()
import django.core.handlers.wsgi 
application = get_wsgi_application() 
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

Comment: application = get_wsgi_application() - is not need

Comment: If You will use 80 port (http) -  configure httpd.conf file.

Comment: Then change permissions of all package of You django-project. For example if You django-project is mysite -  sudo chown -R user:root Path/To/You/Project.  Then:  sudo chmod -R 770 Path/To/You/Project. Then start You httpd service.